# How to keep folder structure in blob storage when using Data Factory to copy file

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I want to copy some files in Blob. My blob Storage has a structure like this:

```
test(blob name)
       A(folder)
           A1.csv
           A2.csv
       B
           B1.csv
           B2.csv
```

However, when I try to use the copy activity in Data Factory, I lose my folder A, B and my result is:

```
test(blob name)
     A1.csv
     A2.csv         
     B1.csv
     B2.csv
```

So, how can I keep A, B and folder tree?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check your copy activity? In the sink tab it should be like this:

[image: Copy behavior]

You probable have selected "Flatten hierarchy".

Hope this helped!

Comment: right, I have the wrong choice of copy behavior. The problem just change copy behavior.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using one copy activity to copy all files to the target folder, make sure that the copyBehavior property of your copy activity is set to PreserveHierarchy.

PreserveHierarchy preserves the file hierarchy in the target folder. The relative path of source file to source folder is identical to the relative path of target file to target folder. You can learn more in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#copy-activity-properties).

[image]